# Binding pivotitem content in WP8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

In my mainpage.xaml I have a pivot control:

```
<Pivot x:Name="Pivot" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding PivotItems}" 
  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PivotItemTemplate}">
</Pivot>
```

which binds it's items to a *PivotsItems* property on my viewmodel.  The pivotitems are shown correctly but i'm not able to bind the content of the pivotitem.

My datatemplate looks like:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PivotItemTemplate">
    <PivotItem>
        <TextBlock Text="Test"></TextBlock>
    </PivotItem>
</DataTemplate>
```

But no content is shown in any pivotitem.

What I wan't to do is to bind the pivotitems (which works) but show a seperate filter for each pivotitem.  In this example I just want to show a TextBlock in each pivotitem.

SOLVED:

I defined the itemtemplate on the pivot control in the page, while i had to add it when populating the list in the vm:

```
PivotItems.Add(new PivotItem { Header = item.Key, ContentTemplate = App.Current.Resources["PivotItemTemplate"] as DataTemplate });
```

Answer (score 2):

Pivot automatically Wraps it's items into PivotItems (like you don't add ListViewItem to a ListViews ItemsTemplate). Just put your content into the DataTemplate.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PivotItemTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="Test"></TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

The header defaults to the DataContext of the PivotItem (so your list item). If you want it to display a certain property, you have to set the HeaderTemplate too:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyProperty}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

If you just keep it as a TextBlock with no further properties, the default style gets applied perfectly.

Comment: Tnx, but still getting empty pivotitems.  The headers are shown correctly.  In this example I expect the same textblock for each pivotitem.